# Derive Input Value Attribute from Iterating through state Maps keys

Tags: javascript, iterator, controlled-component

I'm iterating through keys of a Maps object using a spread operator and would like to know how to derive the value from state.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState( 
    new Map( 
    Object.entries({
    datapoint1: "",
    datapoint2: "",
    datapoint3: "",
    datapoint4: ""
  })
  )
  );


{[...data.keys()].map((datapoint) => {
        return (
          <input
          className="inputboxes"
          id={datapoint}
          // value={} how to get value 
            key={datapoint}
            onChange={handleChange(datapoint)}
          />
        );

      }
      
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the spread operator `[...data]` to work with an array format of the `[key,value]`of my state. I then used the get(key) method which returns a specified element that is associated with the key provided.

```
   value={[...data.get(datapoint)]}
```